# Embedded streetviewpanorama displaying completely different location than default "See Inside" view [google-maps]

Tags: google-maps

Our embedded streetViewPanorama recently started displaying a different/incorrect location for a couple store locations.  Our embedded widget uses the same LatLng coordinates as the full screen google maps link (which display correct location), yet somehow the two no longer match up.

For example, our Vista store which used to work is currently showing the front of a Sams Club instead of the inside of our store: http://www.livingspaces.com/stores/vista.  Yet, when you click our "Full View" link, which uses the same coordinates, you'll see the [expected location](https://www.google.com/maps/@33.172179,-117.2181396,3a,75y,84.59h,82.79t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1siuHgqsr-AyoAAAQYNw4GYQ!2e0!3e2).

Here is the code that creates my streetViewPanorama:

```
/* START OF INSIDE STORE */
var insideStore = new google.maps.LatLng(33.172179, -117.2181396);
var panoramaOptions = {
    position: insideStore,
    zoomControl: false,
    addressControl: false,
    pov: {
        heading:0,
        pitch:0
    }
};
var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'),panoramaOptions);
```

Has anyone run into this issue or know what may be the problem?

Comment: I find you website on other places except vista one works fine, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33087557/embedded-streetviewpanorama-displaying-completely-different-location-than-defaul). You should check the previous code for that, it may similar.

Comment: Yes, the other locations on our site work fine.  The code is the same for these pages - the only difference being the LatLng location.  This is what makes me feel like it may be a cache issue on Google's end.  I'm having trouble finding a support location for google maps.